# NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/util/PropertyUtils

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-bus

I've got a new application and I try to make it working.

I upgraded version of

- **spring-boot** to `2.7.6`
- **spring-cloud** to `3.1.5`

and after it I started to receive following error in tests:

```
13:08:34.679 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: unknown
13:08:34.680 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/util/PropertyUtils
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.shouldProcessEnvironment(ConfigServerConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.cloud.commons.ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:200)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
```

How can I find dependency which contains class `org/springframework/cloud/util/PropertyUtils` ?

Comment: What is Spring Cloud 3.1.5 Check the compatibility matrix https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Comment: Please show your pom or Gradle file

Comment: please read my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this helped me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
  </dependency>
```